# compiling all scss files in all subfolders using gulp

Tags: angular, gulp

I have this angular2 project structure (showing the part where i have the problem ) :

```
|templates
   |index
       -index.scss
       -index.template.html
   |About
       -about.scss
       -about.template.html
```

I want to compile all scss files in index and about folders using gulp, and put the compiled files in the same directory as the scss files. 
Example : 
     index.scss must be compiled and placed in index (folder) as index.css
so that the result will be

```
|templates
     |index
        -index.scss
        -index.css
        -index.template.html
```

how could I compile all of scss files in all templates subfolders using gulp, and the compiled files must be placed in the same subfolder as the scss file ?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: You are right :D , I have just edited the post; Thanks!

Comment: You can specify patterns with gulp.src, i.e. `gulp.src('./templates/**/*.scss') - you'll probably have to do something like that.

Comment: Thank you! that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
gulp.src('./**/**.scss')
   .pipe(scss-to-css-plugin())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Code**

```
gulp.task('sass-style', function() {
  return sass('templates/folder/**/*.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''templates/folder/'));

});
```