# Gulp gulp-less to include component sub-folders

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-less

My less folders contain sub folders (with more on the way). It looks like so...

```
Assets
  |- js
  |- less
       |- students
            |- students.less  // ignores
       |- courses
            |- courses.less   // ignores
       |- teachers 
            |- teachers.less  // ignores
       main.less  // gets successfully
```

Right now my gulpfile.js can find main.less just fine. But how can I go into the sub directories (students, courses, teachers) and grab their respective `.less` files to gulp-less + minify?

This is what I have:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('assets/less/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp - Target all files in a folder and its subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526891/gulp-target-all-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders)

Comment: Also related: [compiling all scss files in all subfolders using gulp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38490611/216074).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `**/*.less` to match all subdirectories.

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('assets/less/**/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
});
```